# I'm adding a js to a Wordpress entry and am not seeing the expected results

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to create some code that will randomly change a specific word in using javascript in a wordpress entry. This is what I have in the wordpress entry:

```
<p>What about a BMW or a <span id="carbrands"> Ford</span>?</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.artifacting.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/wordchanger.js"></script>
```

And this is the js code I am using to change the word "Ford" in the above entry

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var changeWord = function () {
  var words = ['Toyota','Nissan','Kia','Seat','Maybach','Rolls Royce','Fiat','Chrysler','Land Rover','Bentley','Jaguar','McLaren','Vauxhall'];
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
    $("#carbrands").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).text(word)
        }).fadeIn();
}
window.setInterval(changeWord, 3000)
var changeWord2 = function () {
  var words = ['appendages','extenders','peripherals','legs','grippers','flaps'];
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    $("#wings").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).text(word)
        }).fadeIn();
}
window.setInterval(changeWord2, 5000)
// ]]></script>
```

For some reason this is not resulting in the random changing of the word on my wordpress entry. Can anyone give me some suggestions as to why?

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors? Also, I believe that WordPress uses `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: There seem to be several missing semicolons.

Comment: j08691 I am getting this error in the console so I think you are right: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: What result do you get in wp?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`: Make sure your script is inserted after jQuery has been added. For best results add your script to the bottom of the page.

You should also wait for the page to load completely. Wrap your code like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // your code...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If you've added all the required semicolons and the script still doesn't work. I suggest you comment out all the fancy fadeIn-Out sections and test the logic of your code. You can also use console.log() to assist your debugging.